# google maps api - general information

Tags: google-maps

I am looking into using the MAPS API to create a map that will allow me to plot two points to create a route, then allow me to enter total milege for a day and have the map show how far along the route my mielage has taken me.

I am not sure what to call this type of function to search for information.

First, is this possible?  If so, can anyone point me in a direction to start my investigation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how exactly you need it.

a route  consists of [legs](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsLeg), and every leg consists of [steps](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsStep).
Every leg and every step(usually) has a distance-property, so it's possible to calculate the position by looping through every leg end step, sum the distances of the steps and stop it when you reach the mileage.

---

**Explanation of "where to start" :**

The main-class you need ist the [DirectionsService](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsService), it holds all the methods you need when requesting with routes.

1. Create a DirectionsService-instance.
2. request the route, this will be done using the route()-method  of the DirectionsService-instance. The route-method expects a [DirectionsRequest](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRequest)-object as argument, which allows you to define the start and end of the route(as coordinates or adresses)
3. when you got the answer on the request, you'll receive a DirectionsResult-object which you need for rendering the route and also for the desired calculation of the current position.
4. create a instance of the [DirectionsRenderer](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRenderer)-Class to print the route by using the method setDirections(), which expects the DirectionsResult as argument.
5. Now use the DirectionsResult for the calculation/loop described yesterday by using basic javascript. A DirectionsResult will look like this: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&sensor=false
6. Once you calculated the current position draw the [marker](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) at this position

Comment: Thnak you Dr.Molle for the response.  I understand the "leg" issue, my main "do not know where to start" issue you touched on.  "looping through every leg end step, sum the distances of the steps and stop it when you reach the mileage."   What function is available for me to accomplish this?